# How can I escape the message that The authenticity of can't be established for sftp command

Tags: unix

I have a problem with sftp. When I use the command `sftp servername` it prints out:

```
The authenticity of host 'servername(IPaddress)' can't be established.    
ECDSA key fingerprint is 99:68:ca:0c:9f:a3:73:2d:c8:4a:04:60:27:12:5b:13.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Can somebody let me know what I have to change so that this message doesn't come up? I am on AIX server.

Answer (score 0):

1. set the `StrictHostKeyChecking` option to no on the command line, and/or send the key to a null known_hosts file.

   ```
   sftp -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no serverName
   ```

or

2. You can also set these options in your config file, either for all hosts or for a given set of IP addresses or host names. Edit/add config file normally located at `~/.ssh/config`, and at the beginning of the file, add the below lines

   ```
   Host *
       User                   your_login_user
       StrictHostKeyChecking  no
       IdentityFile          ~/my_path/id_rsa.pub
   ```

P.S. config file's permissions should be set to 600 (`-rw-------`)